# Not using php prepare statement when I am not getting an input from a user

Tags: php, security, prepared-statement, sql-injection

**P.S**: I know it is a best practice to user prepared statements all the time, and it should be a habit to use prepared statements. So putting this aside, please just let me know **technically** what can go wrong if I don't write below scenario with `prepare`.

**1.** I am not getting any input from users or any other class file, and I won't in the future.

**2.** I am getting an input from a variable in the same PHP file (an array for example).

**Example:** (`$myID` will be a variable hardcoded in the same PHP file)

```
$myID=12;

$wpdb->query("UPDATE `$table_name` SET `your_column_1` = 1 WHERE `myTable`.`your_column_id` = $myID");
```

Comment: Then where do you get your values from? What is the actual data source then?

Comment: What do you mean by "variable in the same page"? What does "page" refer to here?

Comment: @arkascha by page I meant same php file, I edited the question.

Comment: If that id is a constant value, then why is it a variable? Why not a constant?

Comment: @arkascha dear friend, I just simplified my problem before posting it to stackoverflow so that it is easier to read, so you don't need to focus on details. Normally I have an array, and I am using the elements of my array using a foreach and creating the query.

Comment: _"will be a constant variable"_ No, it will be a variable. Don't rely on convention to assume its value can't change.

Comment: @AlexHowansky constant variable not in terms of programming. I am having trouble with your overdose analytical thinking going on here :D, I just used the word as in english grammer. I am just putting some variables to code by hardcoding, and called them constant. Thats all.

Comment: "I am using the elements of my array using a foreach and creating the query" The benefits of prepared statements go beyond sanitizing data. Once your statement is prepared, execution is far faster with much less overhead. Repeatedly performing a query in a loop is an ideal place to use prepared statements.

Comment: @miken32 Have you measured the difference in execution speed of a prepared statement vs. non-prepared statement? I know there's a difference, but I don't think I'd call it "far faster."

Comment: @BillKarwin I may have been taking a little creative license. It depends on the complexity of the statement, number of iterations, local vs remote database, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tl;DR** This is a very bad idea. You are introducing long-term risk to save a few seconds of coding effort. It is overwhelmingly likely that you will, sooner or later, introduce a SQL injection risk as your code and data evolve.

*If* you:

- are extremely careful about validating your data,
- are extremely careful about constructing your queries,
- are absolutely certain that your data is safe and free of *any* user input (from any source at all, including forms, sensors, APIs, scraping websites, etc.), and
- are absolutely certain that no one will ever modify your data or your code (or reuse your code inappropriately), *including you*,

Then we can say:

- it would be safe to execute queries without prepared statements, and - and this is the important part -
- **you would be living in a fantasy world.**

You can *never* assume *safely* that you can avoid preparing statements. It’s highly, highly likely that your code will break if you do. You could have bad data, overlook a problem, change the code yourself somehow, repurpose the code for something insecure, or make any number of other errors. You may end up doing harmless SQL injection yourself (with, say, a name or spelling like `O’Brien`) or you may get massively hacked...

...all to save a few seconds of coding time.

Short version: either (1) use prepared statements on *every query* that has any kind of variable information or (2) learn the hard way why that’s the rule.

Comment: Just based on the simple code part that I added to my question, is that 2 line of code has any security leaks in it? Assume that I used prepare statement everywhere, except these 2 lines of code.

Comment: If you have perfect control over those variables, perfectly sanitize them, and never make a bad edit that introduces risk, then sure, it’s safe... and you’re being unrealistic. Code changes, and it’s far, far more likely that it results in a vulnerability at some point than not. To put a fine point on it (and I don’t mean this to be rude): don’t be lazy. Code safely, and don’t look for shortcuts. That’s how bugs and major vulnerabilities get written; nobody sets out and says, “I think I’ll write a major security flaw for myself today.” They cut corners to save a few seconds. Don’t do that.

Comment: I am going to give you some insight here, I am creating an sql query to update stocks of products after a new product is added and my variables in the query are, "color," "size", "product category id". This is a wordpress plugin and will only be used by me in admin panel. So the problem caused because of using "in" statement because it is hard to write the query like update column where color in ('black','white'). So I have perfect control over these variables, and the plugin doesn't have a user interface. I just use a button to call the plugin and it updates stocks with the hardcoded details.

Comment: I understand what you’re saying. I’m saying that it’s an error - a big one - to assume that will always be the case, you will never copy-paste this code, you will never add any sources of external input, etc. Preparing queries is good practice and is safe. Concatenating variables directly into your queries is not a good practice and is not wise, no matter how certain you are today that it’s okay. Many, many vulnerabilities have been introduced this way, and you make such a decision at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

> This is a wordpress plugin and will only be used by me in admin panel. So the problem caused because of using "in" statement because it is hard to write the query like update column where color in ('black','white').

If you're developing for WordPress, have you considered using the wpdb API? It makes it pretty easy to add parameters to your SQL queries.

Example of using parameters for an `IN( )` predicate:

```
$colors_array = ["black", "white"];
$placeholders = array_fill(0, count($colors_array), "%s");
$placeholder_list = implode(",", $placeholders);
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        UPDATE $wpdb->stock
        SET quantity = 327
        WHERE color IN ($placeholder_list)
    ", 
    $colors_array
));
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

I agree with Ed Cottrell's advice that you should not compromise on secure programming methods. Use the most secure method and use it consistently.

- You don't have to waste time thinking about whether any given case is "safe enough" to skip using the secure method.
- You don't have to worry if it's still safe after your PHP variables are no longer hard-coded.
- You don't have to worry that someone will copy & paste your code as an example, and they use it in an unsafe way.